# Can't use variable in alert within function

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code as a part of a game I'm making. But for the purposes of finding out what was causing this bug I took the section of code into a new html document.
I am trying to use this code:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
Difficulty = Normal
function ChangeGameMode()
{
  alert (Difficulty + ' game started ');
  }
</script>
<button type="button" class="StartButton" onclick="ChangeGameMode()">Start</button>
</html>
```

When I click the button, I don't get an alert. Nothing happens.

But if I don't use the Difficulty variable in the alert - ie:

```
alert ('Normal' + ' game started ');
```

Then when I use that for the alert instead, it does work.
I am at conplete loss as to what is causing this and I have been pulling my hair out because of it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the `Normal` variable? Did you want a string?

Comment: Btw, you should lowercase all function and variable names unless they're constructors

Comment: Always check the Javascript console for error messages when something "does not work"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't properly defined the `Difficulty` variable. You need to assign it a valid value. `Normal` is not a valid javascript value. You need to wrap it in quotes:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Difficulty = 'Normal';
function ChangeGameMode() {
    alert (Difficulty + ' game started ');
}
</script>
<button type="button" class="StartButton" onclick="ChangeGameMode()">Start</button>
</html>
```

Comment: Derp. I forgot to use normal as a string.
I'm so used to using numbers for my variables instead of words.

Answer (score 0):

Normal must be in quotes:

```
var Difficulty = "Normal";
```